# Is the equation $\det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ -1 & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = 0$ solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This came up when trying to (geometrically) find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix:
(Counterclockwise rotation of 90 degrees about the origin)

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Logically I think there are no answers, but wolframalpha tells me that:
`solve det(lambda*{{1,0},{0,1}}-{{0,-1},{1,0}}) == 0`

has an answer lambda = +-i, now what does 'i' mean here?

Comment: $\pm i$ is exactly correct. Consider a vector in the complex plane and multiply it by $i$. What is the effect? Now, if you are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there are indeed no eigenvalues.

Comment: Is i a variable here, or some constant?

Comment: It is the square root of negative one. The imaginary unit.

Comment: There is a corresponding quadratic equation. THis is solved trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i = \sqrt{-1}$

Your determinant is $1$.

[image: Mathematica session]